# docker-compose: container timezone

Tags: docker, timezone, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Compose to run my stack in my dev environment, but I'm having issues with the timezone in the container being one hour behind my own timezone, breaking mission-critical things and making development very difficult.

I figured this would be a common issue, so I've searched far and wide, but the only two solutions I've found don't work (don't work: no effect).

I've tried two things:

**Attempt 1 - symlinking volumes from the host**
By attempting to mount `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime` as `ro`-volumes, I was hoping the container would have the same timezone as the host. No effect.

**Attempt 2 - setting the variables in the `command`**
Instead of letting Docker Compose use the `ENTRYPOINT` specified in my `Dockerfile`, I set up the `command` in the `docker-compose.yml`-file thus:

```
environment:
    - APPLICATION_ENV=dev-docker
    - TZ=Europe/Stockholm
build: ../../core/document
command: >
  sh -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime &&
  echo $TZ > /etc/timezone &&
  exec /go/bin/documents"
```

Again, no effect at all.

Is there no official way of setting the timezone in Docker containers? I feel this should be a critical issue to more users than me.

Thanks.

**Edit**: the `dockerfile` from the `core/documents`-project, as requested.

```
# This file is intended for use with the GitLab CI tool where the binary has already been built.
FROM golang:1.9.2

# The binary is built and downloaded to the current directory by GitLab CI.
COPY ./documents /go/bin

# Run the program.
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/documents
```

Comment: Could you post the Dockerfile from `core/document`?

Comment: Added as an edit to the original post. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that I never answered this properly. I did find the solution.

**TL;DR:**
Alpine only checks the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm`-file, not the `/etc/localtime`-file.

**Longer answer**
Basically, the step that was missing was that Alpine doesn't check the `/etc/localtime`-path - it only checks the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm`-path (change to your timezone).

In my case, I decided on an arguably unorthodox solution. I wanted to:

- Only copy the timezone I actually wanted, as the `tzdata` package was twice the size than the entire rest of the container; base image and by binary both
- Run the proper `apk tel tzdata`-command and not clean up myself in some weird `rm`-way.
- Not clutter the `tzdata`-packages with other files, or write stuff to it manually (aside from a symlink)

Therefore, I decided to install `tzdata`, copy the time zone I wanted to `/etc/localtime` and then create a symlink for Alpine to still read the file.

I have the following in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN \
    apk --update add curl bash nano tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm /etc/localtime && \
    echo "Europe/Stockholm" > /etc/timezone && \
    apk del tzdata && \
    rm -r /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe && \
    ln -s /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm
```

Answer (score 7):

I have had problems with timezones as well, for me this made the trick:

```
environment:
  - TZ=Europe/Stockholm
```